# Why is connecting to Oracle Express 11 is very slow on Fedora 17?

Tags: fedora, performance, oracle-database

I installed `oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm` on Fedora 17-64-bit. I was wondering why it is very slow, for example when I want to connect to it using Oracle SQL Developer or JDBC in my web application.

Are there any configuration for Fedora or Oracle Express 11 to improve my performance?

I mention that my machine specification is good (8GB RAM , Core i5 CPU).

I installed an Oracle Express on Windows using VirtualBox and when I wanted to connect to it from my Fedora it was slow but when I connected to it locally (in Windows) it connected very fast!

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting) (Same Q on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009677/why-oracle-express-11-is-very-slow-on-fedora-17). Also you'll need to explain in more detail what "slow" means. What exactly is taking a lot of time?

Comment: I cross-post this question because it relate to this site and i wanted both user of sited see my question.

Comment: Well don't. It's off-topic on Stack Overflow anyway. And without any more details, it's not answerable.

Comment: when i wanted to connect to it using "Oracle SQL Developer", it took about 1 minute.

Comment: People spend careers learning how to optimize databases, it is a hard topic.  The first thing you could do is be more specific; how big is the DB, how many reads/writes per second?  How many clients?  etc. etc.  Since you're using oracle you should be able to find a consultant easily enough if money is not a concern.

Comment: What about direct connection through sqlplus? Slow as well?

Comment: It is only a developer database and when i installed it on a windows machine it works faster.

Comment: It is slow With sqlplus too(but a bit faster than sql developer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disabled "firewall" and "SELinux Default Enforcing" and then the problem was solved.
I also added `Device name` (or host name, e.g. saeed-pc) into `hosts` file (located in /etc/hosts):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost saeed-pc
```